# c# networking strangeness

Tags: c#, networking

I am working on a little networking server, and I'm doing it from the latest version of MonoDevelop.

I have a method, PlayerReadLoop, which is passed a trivial Player object, and also passed a tcpClient object. This method is not complete yet, and does not rely on the Player object it is being passed, so, no need to give any info on player. The TcpClient is definitely initialized properly, as I have, in the passed, succeeded at sending messages through that tcpClient.

Here is the method:

```
private void playerReadLoop(Player p, TcpClient c)
{
    byte[] message = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    NetworkStream clientStream = c.GetStream();
    while (true)
    {
        bytesRead = 0;
        try
        {
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            break;
        }
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            break;
        }

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));

    }
}
```

For some reason, the above code does not work! You see,

When I surround the two lines:

```
SCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```

with notation, whether or not my client sends a message, clientStream.Read goes through, and returns zero bytes, indicating a disconnection. My client did not send anything at all, and certainly did not disconnect.

When the two lines are NOT notated, clientStream.read NEVER passes. Whether or not my client sends a message.

Now, if this weren't strange enough, having the above code DIRECTLY after my tcpClient initialization (in the same method that the tcpClient was initialized), the code WORKS! I am not doing anything to the tcpClient, I just pass it directly to the function above, with a Player object that was initialized using the tcpClient. The player object doesn't do anything to the tcpClient, it simply stores it in one of its variables. I don't understand how the simple act of putting this code inside it's own method causes such an obscene difference in behavior!

The client code is simple:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 21255);

client.Connect(serverEndPoint);

NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes("Hello Server!");

clientStream.Write(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length);
clientStream.Flush();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I surround the two lines: [...] with notation"?

Comment: line1; line2; becomes /*line1; line2;*/

Comment: "My client did not send anything at all, and certainly did not disconnect."...But what about the server?  How can you be sure the server-side of that connection did not drop your connection.  Having Wireshark running during network code troubleshooting is a must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush.aspx

Calling Flush on a network stream has no effect whatsoever, so it shouldn't be in your code to begin with.

The read and write operations are blocking operations normally on the sockets. Thus they'll wait till the operation is fully completed. Before reading & writing to the network stream, you're best of checking if they can actually be written or read from. There's properties for that. (more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write.aspx)

Also because Read can return 0, it doesn't mean the client 'disconnected' as written in your code. It just means that no bytes are available yet on the receiving buffer to read from. This also means Read will keep blocking by default untill data is actually beeing sent.

If you're not receiving data, check the port & connection settings on both client & server so that they match.

**EDIT**
Just because you write something on the networkstream, doesn't mean it gets sent over the wire directly. There's a buffer between your code and the actual socket. There's no control over this buffer, only Windows controls it. That's why there's sometimes a delay between your code and the actuall sending.

It also explains why certain settings or code configuration don't seem to have a direct effect. This information is well hidden, and not on the MSDN, but if you dive into the technet documents of Microsoft about socket communication, you'll find alot more juicy bits that explain this. Unfortunatly I cannot share the link at the moment.

Comment: What is odd is that the code works perfectly when it is in a different spot in my execution -- So I definitely know the connection information is correct, and checking for zero bytes seemed to cause read to block until something was sent, or the client disconnected, so, dunno. And then there is the fact that trying to read from the stream somehow stops it from disconnecting! It's very strange behavior, but I'll try checking out waiting for the streams to be ready

Comment: You were right about the read stream returning 0 bytes when there is nothing to be read! For some reason every thing is working now, I have added while loops to await stream activation, all though they have yet to actually be called.

Comment: edited my post, to give you a potential explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on a little networking server

Had you come across the open source c# network communication library [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net)? It is as good as plug and play so you can be up and running immediately. Plus most of the problems you will come across have already have been solved.